# License information for this component not found in VisualBasic

Tags: dll, vb6, licensing, ocx

I want to communicate with serial port in visual basic. I install VB6 on Windows XP sp3.

I downloaded **mscomm32.ocx** and put it in `C:\Windows\System` and `C:\Windows\System32` directories, And successfully register it via `regsvr32` in **Command-Line** and as you see below :

[image]

[image]

Then when I open Visual-Basic components, I can see **Microsoft Common Control 6** and I add it to toolbars :
[image]

But when I doble-click on it to add it the form, The below error appear :
[image]

This is the log :

> Line 422: Cannot load control MSComm; license not found.

Note that, my code has only 80 lines!

Comment: What version of VB6 do you have? If you have the Professional or Enterprise edition and you installed it properly, [MSCOMM32 should have been included](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194784/pl) and you would not have needed to download it. MSCOMM32 was not included  in the Learning edition.

Comment: I have a portable version of Enterprise edition.and in hadn't `mscomm32`

Comment: When you installed the Enterprise edition, Mscomm32 should have been installed with its developer license. What is a "portable version"? Perhaps you're not installing VB6 properly?

Comment: There is no "Portable" version of Visual Studio 6.0, although it is referenced as such on a large number of torrent/pirate sites.  If you've got a legitimate copy of the Enterprise Edition, this control would be included.

Comment: @DWRoelands As you see above, I included it! but the problem is license!

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a Microsoft Support item that may address your issue,

[VB6Cli.exe Fixes License Problems with Visual Basic 6.0](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/194/Q194751/)

Original text:

> ```
> Q194751: FILE: VB6Cli.exe Fixes License Problems with Visual Basic 6.0
> Article: Q194751
> Product(s): Microsoft Visual Basic for Windows
> Version(s): 6.0
> Operating System(s): 
> Keyword(s): kbfile kbtophit kbActiveX kbCtrl kbLicensing kbVBp600 kbGrpDSVB kbDSupport
> Last Modified: 28-MAR-2001
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> The information in this article applies to:
>
> - Microsoft Visual Basic Learning Edition for Windows, version 6.0 
> - Microsoft Visual Basic Professional Edition for Windows, version 6.0 
> - Microsoft Visual Basic Enterprise Edition for Windows, version 6.0 
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> SUMMARY
> =======
>
> VB6Cli.exe is a utility that fixes design-time licenses used by ActiveX controls
> installed with Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0.
>
> NOTE: If you encounter this issue with Visual Basic version 5.0, please see the
> following article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
>   Q181854 FILE: VB5cli.exe Fixes Visual Basic 5.0 Control Installation Problem
>
> MORE INFORMATION
> ================
>
> The following file is available for download from the Microsoft Download
> Center:
>
>   Vb6cli.exe
>   (http://download.microsoft.com/download/vb60ent/Sample30/1/W9XNT4/EN-US/VB6CLI.EXE)
>
> Release Date: Oct-26-1998
>
> For additional information about how to download Microsoft Support files, click
> the article number below to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
>   Q119591 How to Obtain Microsoft Support Files from Online Services
>
> Microsoft used the most current virus detection software available on the date of
> posting to scan this file for viruses. Once posted, the file is housed on secure
> servers that prevent any unauthorized changes to the file.
>
>    FileName               Size
>   ---------------------------------------------------------
>   VBC6.EXE                 32k
>   ENTDAT.DLL               32k
>   LRNDAT.DLL               28k
>   PRODAT.DLL               28k
>   README.TXT               5k
>
> Contents of the README.TXT file included in VB6CLi.exe:
>
> What is VB6Cli.exe?
> -------------------
>
> VB6Cli.exe is a utility that is designed to fix design-time license problems with
> ActiveX Controls that ship with Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0. The utility does not
> fix third-party controls or controls that are not normally installed by
> Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0, nor does it enable the use of Remote Data Object
> (RDO) objects in Visual Basic 6.0 Professional Edition. If you try to use RDO in
> Visual Basic 6.0 Professional Edition, you may also encounter symptoms II and IV
> below. The only way to enable RDO is to install Visual Basic 6.0 Enterprise
> Edition.
>
> VB6Cli.exe will help correct problems with the following symptoms:
>
> Symptom I:
>
> When trying to site a control within a project, Microsoft Visual Basic raises the
> following error dialog:
>
>   License Information For This Component Not Found. You Do Not Have An
>   Appropriate License To Use This Functionality In The Design Environment.
>
> Symptom II:
>
> When trying to compile a project, Microsoft Visual Basic raises the following
> error dialog:
>
>   Compile Error : Permission Denied
>
> Symptom III:
>
> When using the Application Wizard, Microsoft Visual Basic raises an error dialog
> similar to:
>
>   60: Method ~ of Object ~ failed
>
> Symptom IV:
>
> When trying to run a project, Microsoft Visual Basic raises the following error
> dialog:
>
>   Runtime Error '429' : ActiveX Component Can't Create Object
>
> Which ActiveX controls does VB6Cli.exe work with?
> -------------------------------------------------
>
> The following is a list of ActiveX controls that VB6Cli.exe can fix:
>
> ActiveX Control                     FileName        Version      Edition
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ADO Data Control 6.0                 MSADODC.OCX    6.00.8171    L,P,E
> Chart Control 6.0                   MSCHRT20.OCX    6.00.8177      P,E
> Comm Control 6.0                    MSCOMM32.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> Common Dialog Control 6.0           COMDLG32.OCX    6.00.8169    L,P,E
> Data Bound List Controls 6.0        DBLIST32.OCX    6.00.8169    L,P,E
> DataGrid Control 6.0                MSDATGRD.OCX    6.00.8169    L,P,E
> DataList Controls 6.0               MSDATLST.OCX    6.00.8169    L,P,E
> DataRepeater Control 6.0            MSDATREP.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> FlexGrid Control 6.0                MSFLXGRD.OCX    6.00.8169    L,P,E
> Hierarchical FlexGrid Control 6.0   MSHFLXGD.OCX    6.00.3005    L,P,E
> Internet Transfer Control 6.0         MSINET.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> MAPI Controls 6.0                   MSMAPI32.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> Masked Edit  Control 6.0            MSMASK32.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> Multimedia Control 6.0                 MCI32.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> PictureClip Control 6.0             PICCLP32.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> RemoteData Control 6.0               MSRDC20.OCX    6.00.8169        E
> Rich Textbox Control 6.0            RICHTX32.OCX    6.00.8169    L,P,E
> SysInfo Control 6.0                  SYSINFO.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> Tabbed Dialog Control 6.0           TABCTL32.OCX    6.00.8169    L,P,E
> Windows Common Controls-3 6.0       COMCT332.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
> Windows Common Controls 5.0 (SP2)   COMCTL32.OCX    6.00.8022    L,P,E
> Windows Common Controls 6.0         MSCOMCTL.OCX    6.00.8177    L,P,E
> Windows Common Controls-2 5.0 (SP2) COMCT232.OCX    6.00.8022    L,P,E
> Windows Common Controls-2 6.0       MSCOMCT2.OCX    6.00.8177    L,P,E
> Winsock Control 6.0                 MSWINSCK.OCX    6.00.8169      P,E
>
> L = Learning Edition
> P = Professional Edition
> E = Enterprise Edition
>
> How do I use VB6Cli.exe?
> ------------------------
>
> VB6Cli.exe requires that an edition of Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 be installed on
> the system where the utility is going to be used.
>
> Before running the VB6Cli.exe utility, make sure there are no other applications
> running.
>
> Simply double-click on VB6Cli.exe through the Windows Explorer. The utility
> detects Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0, and installs the required design-time
> licenses for the edition detected.
>
> If successful, you will see a dialog box similar to the following:
>
>   "Enterprise Design Licenses Have Been Installed Successfully"
>
> VB6Cli.exe also offers a silent mode. Running the VB6Cli.exe from a command
> prompt with a "/q" will run the utility without any user interface. Result codes
> can be captured and used by other applications to test if the licenses were
> installed.
>
> Result Codes And Error Messages
> -------------------------------
>
> Exit Code 0   : Licenses for that Edition were installed
> Exit Code 1   : Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 was not detected on this system
> Exit Code 2   : Could Not Load A Support Utility Library
> Exit Code 3,4 : At Least 1 Design License Was Not Properly Installed
> Exit Code 5   : Unable To Install Any Design Licenses
> Exit Code 6   : There Was An Unspecified Error With The VBC6 Utility
>
> Disclaimer
> ----------
>
> The utility discussed in this article is provided "as is" and Microsoft does not
> guarantee that it can be used in all situations. Although Microsoft support
> engineers can help with the use of this product, it is not supported. Use this
> tool at your own risk.
>
> REFERENCES
> ==========
>
> For additional information, please see the following articles in the Microsoft
> Knowledge Base:
>
>   Q194784 INFO: Controls Shipped with Visual Basic 6.0
>
>   Q181854 FILE: VB5cli.exe Fixes Visual Basic 5.0 Control Installation Problem
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this license:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\4250E830-6AC2-11cf-8ADB-00AA00C00905]
```

which you can copy from a machine where VisualStudio6 is installed.
I'll used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to detect this.

Comment: Good tip to use procmon