# VB6.0 extension/reference bug, getting error "Method or data member not found"

Tags: vb6

*Note: I'm not an experienced programmer*

I've been handed some old VB6.0 programs for my work, which were compiling and running successfully in the past, but now when I try to compile, the error "Method or data member not found" is coming up on some ".Text" property calls.

I'm very confident that it's most likely not the code because it was working before it was assigned to me, so possibly the issue is extensions/references that are no longer accessible by the program. However, I'm sure some people will want to see the code so I've provided a few `.Text` calls, all of which are following a text field. For legal reasons, I can't copy the program but here are a few calls:

```
'Ex1: Line 312 frmMain     
Print #gintAteDataFile, Tab;  gstrDate;  Tab;  gstrtime;  Tab;  Tab;  “Technician: “;  frmTechId.mebTechId.Text

'Ex2: Line 4 frmSerialNumber     
gstrSerialNumber = MaskEdBox1.Text

'Ex3: Line 34 frmComSetup      
If IPControl1.IsBlank Or mebPortNumber.Text = vbNullString Then
```

I have been unable to locate an answer on Google. Does anyone know what references or extensions are necessary for VB6.0 for a property such as ".Text" to not be called correctly? Thank you

Comment: Sometimes when components cannot be loaded VB6 substitutes them with a placeholder control (A picture box iirc) that does not have a .Text property, so verify that those controls are what they actually should be.  What happens if you right click on one of those `.Text` properties in the source and click Definition?

Comment: Yes, along with what Alex wrote, ensure that all of the COM components are properly installed and licensed on the machine.  Installation can often be accomplished by installing the actual software (which in turn installs components).  If they need licensing, that's another step (Something like this... 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381061/license-information-for-this-component-not-found-in-visualbasic).  Once the OCX is installed, restart VB6.. but, if controls have been converted to a Label, you may need to undo that.  Check the forms and control type for MaskEdBox1 & mebPortNumber.

Comment: @User51 do you know what the COM components are called? Looking through the components window, theres a list of "controls" where some are checked off. Does proper installation/license mean they would be checked off?

Comment: @AlexK. When I right click on ".Text", a message pop up happens saying "Identifier under cursor is not recognized" When I right click on MaskEdBox1, it says "Cannot jump to MaskEdBox1 because it is hidden"

Comment: From the code you posted, it apperas that the offending control in question is a "Masked Edit Box" (MSMASK32.ocx). Search your system for it _(usually in Windows\SysWOW64 for 64-Bit systems, Windows\Sytem32 for 32-bit systems)_. If the file is present, you may need to (re-)register it with regsvr32.

Comment: [Added] Here's a screenshot of how the control looks like in VB6's control toolbox: https://www.thevbprogrammer.com/Ch10/10-07-MaskedEdit.htm

Comment: @HelO'Ween Yeah, that control isn't showing up... I tried registering it but the following error message popped up: "The module "MSMASK32.ocx" was loaded but the call to DIIRegisterServer failed with error code 0x8002801c." Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using source control, look to see if any files have been changed unexpectedly. That's often the easiest way to see if VB6 automatically tried to change things because of missing references. You might see this in a VBP or FRM file for instance.

Comment: You need to run regsvr32 with administrative privileges: Right-click on Command Prompt  -> "Run as Administrator". Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the first place.

Comment: Don't forget to run the regsv32.exe from windows\SysWOW64

Comment: @HelO'Ween I reregistered it but I am still getting the initial error when I try to compile. Are there any other missing references you can think of?

Comment: You might now experience the problem @AlexK. mentioned in his 1st comment. Look in the folder where your form files _(*.frm)_ are stored. If VB replaced a non-existing control with a PictureBox, it creates a log file, name (original_form_name).log, e.g. for _Form1.frm_ the log file is name _Form1.log_. You now face the task to undo VB's replacement. Best way to handle that is having a backup copy of the original project at hand and copy the offending forms _(*.frm and related *.frx)_ over. If you don't have a backup ... well, that's a tedious manual task then, I'm afraid.

Comment: @HelO'Ween In the folder with the .frm files, I found four .log files. However, these .log file names each have respective .frm files of the same name in that folder. Are these the files you're referring to? Within the .log files, there are lists of line numbers with a sort of error message description: ex "Line 35: class MSMask.MaskEdBox of control MaskEdBox1 was not a loaded control class."

Comment: Yes, these are the log files I was referring to. Keep those. Open the actual form on your project and select the control referred to in the log file. It most likely now is a Picturebox instead of the control pointed out in the log file (MSMask.MaskEdBox in your example). Now you need to replace the Picturebox control with an actual MaskEditBox (or whichever other control was the offender) of the same name. As I said, it's a tedious task, but as you answered "yes" when asked "...continue loading?", that's VB6's way of handling unresolved control references.

Comment: Try removing ".Text". If I remember correctly, textboxes in vb6 default to ".text" when the extension is omitted.

Comment: @HelO'Ween When I open the form and check the object, it looks like there is a MaskEditBox, but I'm not sure. How do you delete a control?

Comment: How can you be not sure? Click on the control and the property window tells you the type of control. And you delete controls with the most natural/intuitive action: click on it, then press the DEL key. I don't mean to be offensive, but we helped you figure out your original problem and told you how to fix it. Teaching you the basics of VB6's IDE isn't what SO is for.

Comment: @HelO'Ween I'm sorry about that, but I finally got it working. Thank you very much!